# How to generate Getter and Setter for Typescript in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm used to using webstorm to generate getter and setter for classes.

Is there any way to do it with VSCode in short steps?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A VS Code plugin that works to create Java style getters and setters (accessor and mutator methods) is Wilson Godoi's **TypeScript's Getters and Setters Object Oriented Programming Style**.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wilson-Godoi.wg-getters-and-setters

[image]

Comment: Its a good plugin, however for my project, the get method is like this 
`get account(){return this._account ;}` . 
Its a different kinds of get method and the one he gave only returns whole function instead in my project, I think it has something to do with the typescript version.

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn the JS accessors are fine, but sometimes they're undesirable. The main case I've seen is when we want to send an object to the server and that object gets serialized then deserialized. In that case, the accessors won't be there and you'll need to use the `_account` property and models will differ from frontend to backend.

Comment: This extension is too old and doesn't generating for protected properties.

Comment: @kodmanyagha I cannot delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 45):

This feature is shipped builtin with Visual Studio Code 1.24 (May 2018); see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_generate-gettersetter-refactoring

Basically you select the line with the property, then a Quick Action bulb is shown which you have to click. Then you can generate the getters/setters.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  As @John Archer says, you have to select the line.  That means you highlight the entire line of the property, not just putting the cursor over the property name.  They really should enable it for just cursor placement as well.

Comment: Can we generate getter/setter for multiple properties? Selecting multiple properties and performing the above step generate getter/setter for only one property.

Comment: This is an answer that explains how to achieve refactoring without any plugins. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 27):

The shortcut is **Ctrl+Shift+R** after highlighting the property.

Longer method: Right click on the property. Then click on refactor from the popup menu.

Currently, vscode has no feature to mass generate getters and setters for all class properties at once like in other IDEs so it has to be done one property at a time.

Comment: I get "no refactoring available" when I do this (mac version)

Answer (score 2):

write **prop** in service file or any .ts file and hit enter!

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer the OP's question but still good to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

May someone correct me who knows it better, but as far as I know the bare VS Code is not capable of providing this convenience. I'm sure that there exist certain plugins you can use, but I don't know any name.

**Edit**

Maybe **TypeScript Toolbox** is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

To generate getter and setters in typescript :

1)Download and install the TypeScript Toolbox extension in vscode. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DSKWRK.vscode-generate-getter-setter?

2)Press Ctrl+Shift+X or Cmd+Shift+X to open the Extensions viewlet. Find the Go extension, click on it to open the Extension Editor.

3) You can view the Visual Studio Code settings for the Go extension along with their default values and description in the product itself.
 [image]

4) tick the option for Use 'getValue' and 'setValue' instead of 'get value' and 'set value'.

[image]

How to use :

1) Press Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P

2) Enter and search for command Generate All Getter and Setter then hit Enter.

[image]

Comment: Following your instructions yields no change to my source. I issue the command to generate the getters and setters, but nothing happens.